Release Mysql Row Locks Manually
I got a lock wait time-out exception when I tried updating one MySQL table row. I don't have this problem with other rows of the table. I restarted the application but the lock not been released yet.
how can I release the lock manually?

Row locks are released when the transaction in which they were created ends.
If you restarted the application, that definitely would have ended all transactions started by that application.
So either some other client (not your application) was holding a transaction open with locks, or else the application restarted and immediately began locking things.
The best way to deal with lock wait timeouts is to ensure all transactions finish promptly after they acquire locks.
